# recv is always reading 0 bytes after second recv call

Tags: c, windows, sockets, winsock

I have a TCP server running on a platform which reads bytes from a buffer and sends all the bytes over the network in one send call:

```
send(sSocket.client_sock, base, frb_size, 0);
```

frb_size is 2_228_224 bytes in size.

On the receiving end I am trying to buffer the data:

```
while(1) {
    while(total != size) {
        r = recv(my_socket->sock, buf, 8192-total, 0);
        memcpy(buffer+total, buf, r);
        total += r;
    }
  //some code dealing with manipulating the buffer with SDL
}
```

Where I have a smaller buffer `buf` that has a size of 8192. When read it uses memcpy to place it into the proper position inside buffer which is size 2_228_224.

My problem is that after the first iteration all proceeding iterations return r being 0 meaning the socket has been closed as per documentation. What is also weird is that no matter what sized `buf` I use, it always returns the full number of bytes on the first iteration. For example 8192 bytes would be returned in the above code, if I change the sizes to 65507 it will return 65507, but if i change it to 2_228_224 it will never return the full buffer.

Meanwhile when I do:

```
while(1) {
   r = recv(my_socket->sock, buffer, size, 0);
  //some code dealing with manipulating the buffer with SDL
}
```

Where size is the size of buffer (2_228_224). r never returns 0 when debugging, but it also never has the full number of bytes that make up the sent input.

Am I doing something wrong with the socket API on windows? Is there a way to make Winsock sockets block until all number of bytes are received?

Thanks.

Comment: Just an observation, but your code should check the return value returned by `recv` to validate that it is not `-1` (error value for broken socket) before invoking `memcpy` on the subsequent line.

Comment: As a matter of fact, you should check return value from your `send` call.  Typically blocking sockets will send all of the buffer passed to it.  But if your socket is non-blocking, send could return a value less than the buffer sized passed into it.  Is it possible that any of your sockets are configured for non-blocking operations?  Or that your `send` function is returning a value less than expected.

Comment: I will check the TCP server right now. It is on a custom platform which is not well documented so I do not know if the default configuration is non-blocking or not. As far as the receiving side goes, everything is default meaning it should be in a blocking mode.

Comment: @selbie the send calls on the server side are indeed returning the full length of the buffer wanting to be sent (2_228_224) so I am pretty sure the socket is in a blocking state. The issue must appear to be on the client side regarding the recv calls I would imagine.

Comment: Get ready to face-palm -- you've written `8192-total` in your `recv` call.  After you've read the first 8192 bytes and have `total==8192`, how many bytes are you asking `recv` to read??

Comment: @K.A.Buhr Wow. face-palm indeed. I am astonished I didn't catch that. Issue aside, how could I create a recv loop to gather only 2_228_224 number of bytes, no more no less. I had an idea when I implemented it that as the buffer grew I would only request the remainder of the buffer. Either my idea was wrong or my implementation.

Comment: A face-palm that couild have been avoided by simplifying and adding an extra, easily-debugged, temp var, 'int readlength=8192-total;'   Don't be afraid of extra temp vars.  With no debug and optimization on, it's no extra code.  Do be afraid of compound expressions whose result cannot easily be read with a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, using `8192-total` isn't right.  To read up to `size` bytes exactly, use something like this:

```
while(total < size) {
    int bytes = size - total;
    if (bytes > 8192) bytes = 8192;
    r = recv(my_socket->sock, buf, bytes, 0);
    if (r <= 0) {
        /* handle this! */
        break;
    }
    memcpy(buffer+total, buf, r);
    total += r;
}
```

At each iteration, it attempts to read the number of bytes left out of the total but capped at the size of the input buffer.

It's important to handle `r <= 0` and `break` out of the loop to avoid an infinite loop (if `r == 0` repeatedly) or a segfault (if `r == -1` repeatedly pushes `total` negative).

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't even bother using `buf` at all, it is redundant and a bottleneck. I would have `recv()` read directly into `buffer` instead, then you don't have to artificially restrict the size of each read iteration, it will read as much as is actually available: `while (total < size) { r = recv(my_socket->sock, buffer + total, size - total, 0); if (r <= 0) { /* handle this! */ break; } total += r; }`